# How can I use the Hololens API in .net maui or blazor?

Tags: c#, http, blazor, maui, hololens

I'm developing two apps, one in blazor and another one in .net maui. My problem is, I can't receive the data from the API of the HoloLens. I tried with Postman and with Postman it did work, but no idea why in my code it doesn't work. I tried with public APIs and with some with Basic Auth and those did work, What  am I missing? (I also tried the cookie Postman recommends you in the code snippet you can copy of it, but nothing).

The code in .net maui:

```
 var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:1234"));

 // Set Authorization header
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
 var url = $"https://Hololens_IP/api/power/state";
     var response =
     await client.GetAsync(url);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content.Result.ToString());
  }
```

I saw in the website of the HoloLens they use a CSRF cookie, but it didn't work. What I tried:

```
response.Headers.Add("Cookie", "CSRF-Token=TokenOfTheCredentials");
```

I tried with a public API with basic auth a it did work, changing the user and password, changed the result (if you were logged in, or not).

Edit: i found a website which tries something similar what i want, but i already tried it and no result, same error
Code:

```
        private void Initialize()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ameijers", "********");

        client = new HttpClient(handler);
    }
```

[this is the source](https://www.appzinside.com/2017/08/18/how-to-use-the-device-portal-api-of-hololens-take-a-picture/).

Answer (score 1):

You might be attempting to fetch APIs that are running on a localhost server. Perhaps you want to run these APIs on your Android emulator, which may not be able to fetch data from the localhost server. In this case, you can use a dev tunnel or an IP address in your HTTP request.

Comment: the hololens API runs in the same network, i tried in a real device in the same network and the error is the same, "Connection Failure", i really would like to know if there is a way to get more info of the error.